# Error in Flutter : flutter: Error : NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

once user is authenticated by firebase I am getting UID returned but then unable to open the home page.
I am able to print the user IF on console but it is not shifting to next page

validateandSubmit() async {

```
  if (validateandSave()) {
  try {


            FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance
                    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password))
                .user; 

            print('User is valid and saved');
            print('Loggedin: USerId ${user.uid}');
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');

          } catch (e) {
            print('Error : $e');
          }
        }
      }

      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Fint'),
            ),
            body: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: new Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: new Column(children: <Widget>[

                      new TextFormField(
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                        validator: (value) =>
                            value.isEmpty ? 'Email cannot be empty' : null,
                        onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
                      ),
                      new TextFormField(
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                        validator: (value) =>
                            value.isEmpty ? 'Password cannot be empty' : null,
                        onSaved: (value) => _password = value,
                        obscureText: true,
                      ),
                      new RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Login'),
                        onPressed: validateandSubmit
                      ),

                    ]))));
      }
    }
```

Comment: try replacing `/home` to `home`

Comment: @Adnankarim same error still

Comment: @Ank_90 have you defined a onGenerateRoute callback?

Comment: no. what is onGenerateRoute? I have not defined this

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Home()));
```

Comment: Hey Ridha : still same error. I believe this has to do with the context value

Comment: can you update your question and paste the whole code